# can you help me to make like this navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

[image]

hello can you help me to make a navbar like this navbar .. I made already but it's not good , it's working with just one width , and if I a change the width lettel it just doen't work good

Code:

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="beg-container">
    <!-- beg-->
    <li>
      <!-- insusfful-->
      <ul class="left-container">
        <!-- left-->
        <li class="protectionn" style="width: 276px; border-right: 1px solid lightgray;">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/protection.png" width="20px;">payment protection program</a>
        </li>
        <li style="width: 119px;  border-right: 1px solid lightgray; "><a href="#">how we work</a></li>
        <li class="televesionn" style=" padding-left: 10px">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/televesion.png" width="20px"> watch our latest film</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- insusfful-->
      <ul class="right-container">
        <!-- right -->
        <li><a href="#">post buy requirement</a></li>
        <li style="width: 150px; border-left: 1px solid lightgray;" style="width: 276"><a href="#">dowload app</a></li>
        <li style="width: 50px;  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">help</a></li>
        <li style="width: 175px;  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">+9196969696</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
<!-- end of navbar -->
```

Comment: if you can see the image above ....
it's the navbar i want to make

Comment: see my answer as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will see it better in bigger screen**

```css
  li,ul{
    display: flex;
}
ul{
   justify-content: space-between; 
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="beg-container">
    <!-- beg-->
    <li>
      <!-- insusfful-->
      <ul class="left-container">
        <!-- left-->
        <li class="protectionn" style="width: 276px; border-right: 1px solid lightgray;">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/protection.png" width="20px;">payment protection program</a>
        </li>
        <li style="width: 119px;  border-right: 1px solid lightgray; "><a href="#">how we work</a></li>
        <li class="televesionn" style=" padding-left: 10px">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/televesion.png" width="20px"> watch our latest film</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- insusfful-->
      <ul class="right-container">
        <!-- right -->
        <li><a href="#">post buy requirement</a></li>
        <li style="width: 150px; border-left: 1px solid lightgray;" style="width: 276"><a href="#">dowload app</a></li>
        <li style="width: 50px;  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">help</a></li>
        <li style="width: 175px;  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">+9196969696</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```